# Replacing base ubuntu ros packages with mine compiled from source

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, ubuntu, packages, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using ros groovy on armv7l, and I'm getting a bus error from from roscpp_serialization.

The error is well documented (on this forum too) and It seems that there is a patch that fixes it, but it hasn't made it into my ubuntu packages yet.
And I can't find a way to replace this package in my ros build.

If I try to apt-get remove ros-groovy-roscpp-serialization, based on dependencies almost all of ros-groovy-* will be removed.

Is there a way to supersede binary packages with compiled ones ?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/98001/replacing-base-ubuntu-ros-packages-with-mine-compiled-from-source/) by [mtourne](https://answers.ros.org/users/7136/mtourne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2013-11-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok it seems that using catkin it was as simple as :

cloning the repo of roscpp into catkin/src
and then doing catkin_make

Conveniently catkin seems to export a LD_LIBRARY_PATH so that the library compiled in catkin take precedence over the rest of ros.

---

Originally posted by [mtourne](https://answers.ros.org/users/7136/mtourne/) with karma: 36 on 2013-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2013-11-07**:
I just tried and did not experience that: I created a package called map_msgs in catkin/src, with appropriate package.xml and CMakeLists.txt, compiled with catkin_make. it compiled fine, but at the same time my CMakeLists was sort of empty. But when I roscd map_msgs I landed in /opt/ros/...

**Comment by [mtourne](https://answers.ros.org/users/7136/mtourne/) on 2013-11-07**:
Did you call $ source /path/to/catkin/devel/setup.bash ?

It should setup catkin as the first thing in you ROS_PACKAGE_PATH env variable.

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2013-11-08**:
seems that after a while ros figures that I have a map_msgs package. It's not immediate though. I wonder what's the exact behavior and when is the cache refreshed...